# SQL Select only last row's username

Tags: sql

I got my db and I only want to get my last row's username.

The database is named `servers` and the table is `log`:

```
timestamp           | username   
--------------------+------------
2020-11-15 05:45:31 | john   
2020-11-15 05:45:59 | juliet 
2020-11-15 05:49:00 | borat  
2020-11-15 05:49:03 | borat
```

As I mentioned I'm trying to get this:

Output: `borat`

I tried using:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp), username 
FROM log
```

But I'm only getting the correct timestamp and not the right username,
and my output is also way longer than what I'm expecting.

Output: MAX(timestamp) `juliet 2020-11-15 05:49:03`

Does anyone know the solution how to filter only my last record ?

Comment: the answer is closely connected to your DBMS and its version.

Comment: tag a db name....

Comment: Strictly speaking, a relational database system doesn't know anything like a "last row", as rows aren't ordered - they may only be ordered when displayed as output to a query. However, some systems have added functionality to achieve what you are looking for, e.g. MS Sql Server. So the requests to name the database you are working with make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using *mysql* as DBMS as *php*(*deleted tag*) suggests, then use order your data descendingly by `timestamp` value, and only pick the first one by `LIMIT` clause assuming ties do not matter

```
SELECT *
  FROM log
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, Do you think it's possible to get my output just with my db username. Or do I need to cut my output to only get the username

Comment: haha, Yes perfect! Sorry I completely forgot for a moment, Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome @Alpha.Ars , but as a future reference, don't forget to tag your DBMS and it's version yet.